# AWS Load Balancer health check fails for url with #

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I have set up my EC2 load balancer health check to point to a url with a `#` in it like `/#/applications`

When I ssh into the box and curl the url I get a Response code of 200.

However the load balancer gives this error:

`Health checks failed with these codes: [400]`

If I change the health check URL to be `/` then the load balancer say it is fine.

I am suspecting it could be a url encoding issue. Are there any restrictions on what characters are allowed in the URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` is not a valid character in the request URI.  The `#` symbol marks the beginning of the URL fragment.

When you access a URL with `#`, the URI is truncated by the browser at the `#` before it is sent to the server.  Servers never see this -- it's for client-side use only.

It is thus invalid in a health check and the server is correct to reject it as `400 Bad Request`.  Access a URL on your site with a fragment from a browser and you will notice that the `#` is not logged by the web server because the browser doesn't send it.

If for some reason you're actually needing a url-encoded `#`, that would be written as `%23` but I would not expect this to be what you are looking for.